# onedriveApiBrowser sample project - AAD auth fails

Tags: azure, sharepoint, onedrive

I am trying to simply connect to the onedrive API so I thought that using an existing sample project may be the way to go.  Unfortunately all my attempts at connecting to Onedrive for Business using AAD results in a "BAD Request" error.

So, I have opened the sample project in Visual Studio 2015 and have it working without errors.
I have a Sharepoint development site working (using it for Add-in dev at the moment)
I created the App in Azure from Visual Studio which worked fine, however, the setup would not accept the production name of my sharepoint site (ie: myorgname.sharepoint.com) but would only accept the temporary url (ie myorgname.onmicrosoft.com).
I have entered the settings as follows (as per sample project instructions)

```
private const string AadClientId = "67a34ew-...";
public const string AadReturnUrl = "localhost:8080";
public const string AadTargetUrl = "myorgname.onmicrosoft.com";
```

To be honest, the only setting I am sure about is **AadClientId**.  I have found mixed information about the **AadReturnUrl** value and the **AadTargetUrl** value should be - so either of these could be a problem.

I run the code and select File > Sign in to AAD
I enter my office 365 email address (which has full admin rights to Sharepoint and Azure)
And from that I receive a "BAD Request error".

On looking through the VS immediate window I find the following:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory ... TokenCache: Looking up cache for a token
OneDriveApiBrowser.vshost.exe ... TokenCache: Looking up cache for a token
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory ... TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache
OneDriveApiBrowser.vshost.exe ... TokenCache: No matching token was found in the cache
```

I can find no reference to TokenCache in the documentation.  Is anyone able to shed some light into what might be missing?

Regards

Greg J

Answer (score 0):

ok, i kept beavering away at this and finally had success!

indeed the issue was related to the values for AadReturnUrl and AadTargetUrl.

The correct settings are as follows:

```
AadReturnUrl = "urn:.....:oauth:2.0:oob";
AadTargetUrl = "myorgname.sharepoint.com";
```

AadReturnUrl comes from Azure > Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > [Select App] > Settings > Redirect URIs.

When my app was created in Azure from Visual Studio it created this entry.

I managed to connect to my Shared Documents folder.  The Sample app allowed me to successfully upload a file and download a file.